# Enterprise workflow management app with complex activity dependencies

Tags: project-management, finance, workflow

In our company, we need to streamline month end close process which consists of many activities. Each activity can have multiple successors and predecessors (n:n relationship). Activities can be somewhat sorted to processes, but some activities appear in more processes.

I am looking for an app that should automatically start tasks without any predecessors every month, provide to-do lists for accountants, overview for managers. When activity is completed, it should start dependent activities (if all predecessors are completed).

App should also include user management (LDAP sync) and visualization of dependencies.

Can you point me to some applications that meet these requirements?